# Seeking a static instance of SecureRandom rule in PMD

Tags: java, pmd

I am researching PMD repo in the following link
[repo link](https://github.com/pmd/pmd/tree/81739da5caff948dbcd2136c17532b65c726c781/pmd-java)

So what I am looking for is a rule that would make sure that

***you should only be using the primed static SecureRandom instance***

( this is mainly because application, if the object is not being reused, is getting slow and I mean like 90 seconds slower to do the seeding and all other stuff that does in the background, so the solution is to create SecureRandom and reuse it if required )

but from what I managed to find in the repository are these two occurrences.

None of them are speaking about using static SecureRandom instance. Am I missing something or is it just not there/covered in PMD?

[Occurrence no.1](https://github.com/pmd/pmd/blob/81739da5caff948dbcd2136c17532b65c726c781/pmd-java/src/test/resources/net/sourceforge/pmd/lang/java/rule/security/xml/InsecureCryptoIv.xml)

[Occurrence no.2](https://github.com/pmd/pmd/blob/81739da5caff948dbcd2136c17532b65c726c781/pmd-java/src/main/resources/category/java/security.xml)

Answer (score 1):

I don't think, there is such a rule yet. Feel free to create a issue at https://github.com/pmd/pmd/issues with the rule suggestion.

I think, it would fit into the category "security".
The existing rules in this category can be seen here: https://pmd.github.io/latest/pmd_rules_java_security.html